# MATLAB filtering a signal results in NaN

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, signal-processing

I am loading a wav file into matlab and trying to implement a sound Equalizer 
I am using many bandpass filters on different regions in order to implement some effects on the sound
This is an example of part of the code :

```
[b3,a3]=butter(6,[300 500]/22050,'bandpass');
[b4,a4]=butter(6,[750 1250]/22050,'bandpass');
```

These filters are realized correctly and I got the corresponding coefficients
However, when i try to filter the signal, i get that f3 is NaN for all entries, whereas f4 is correctly computed! I checked that my input wav file doesn't have NaN entries, and this is clear since f4 was a success. This is the code I'm using to read the file and to use the filters:

```
x=wavread('sampleseg (1).wav');
f3= filter(b3,a3,x);
f4= filter(b4,a4,x);
```

Any idea what can i do to solve this? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It might be because your sound file does not have frequency components in the `[300 500]` range.  Did you plot the spectra of that sound file to see if you had components there?

Comment: Yes I did check that, it has frequency components over the band 0 to 3khz ...

Comment: That is so weird... did you try changing the order of the filter for `[300,500]`?  What about slightly changing the observation window... like `[250,550]`?

Comment: Show us the data. What is x?

Comment: I've had this problem before. The problem is that `butter` is numerically unstable when computing the _a,b_ filter coefficients. The solution is to have `butter` output the __zero-pole representation__ of the filter, not the _a_, _b_ coefficients. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664631/eeg-bandpass-filter-in-mat-lab) and [Matlab's documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bt5pm8a). Please let me know if this solves your issue, so that I can mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: @LuisMendo ah that explains it. Great tip! Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng This is another one I learned the hard way :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thx alot, yes the problem was solved! Is the problem specific to butter or to other filters like ellip and cheby1? cz i have tried all these types with no use...

Comment: @husseinhammoud I don't really know about the others. `butter` is actually the one I use most often.

Comment: I can't mark as duplicate because the other answer doesn't have upvotes or has been accepted.

Comment: @LuisMendo  You can answer here if you want and i will accept it-- thx alot for everything, you have saved my day ^.^

Comment: Glad I could help :-) I prefer not to answer here, because the answer would essentially be a copy of the original one. If you feel the original answer helped you, you can upvote it there, and maybe then I can mark this question as duplicate