# Matlab vector return to multiple vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, return, signal-processing

```
num = zeros(1,freq);
den = zeros(1,freq);
for R = 1:freq
    [num(R), den(R)]=butter(4, [0.1 0.9]);
end
```

I thought it was quite trivial but once I run it, I get:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that both `num` and `den` will contain multiple coefficients:

> `[b,a] = butter(n,Wn)` returns the transfer function coefficients of an nth-order lowpass digital Butterworth filter with normalized cutoff frequency `Wn`.
>
> `b`,`a` — Transfer function coefficients
>   row vectors

As copied from the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html)

The way to get your code working would be to either set `num` and `den` to a matrix, or to a cell array:

```
num = zeros(freq,4);
den = zeros(freq,4);
for R = 1:freq
    [num(R,:), den(R,:)]=butter(4, [A(R) B(R)]); % matrix
end
for R = 1:freq
    [num{R}, den{R}]=butter(4, [A(R) B(R)]); % cell
end
```

Probably the matrix is better suited for your purposes.

Comment: I knew it was a silly mistake, but after 30min looking clueless at it I needed someone else help . Thanks for your time!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help

Comment: @MiguelHorta Beware of the `b`,`a` output form of `butter`. It can easily give large numerical errors. The zero-pole form avoids that. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23665440/2586922)