# How do I properly design a digital FIR filter?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, digital-filter

I want to design a series of optimal filters for ultrasonic signals. The filter order is fixed at 16 and I want the filter to have a passband for a list of ranges, i.e. (16kHz-38kHz, 17kHz-39kHz etc.). I've been using Matlab's Filter Designer and trying to different design inputs in a trial and error manner. What method can I use to find the optimal filter design algorithm (Remez, least-windows or something else) rather than haphazardly throwing inputs to the wall and seeing what looks best (I'm looking for a filter that best attenuates in the stopbands and has a flat frequency response in the passband, given my filter order constraint).

Comment: For the flattest possible passband you want a [Butterworth filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter). You can design it with the function [`butter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html). Be sure to [avoid the transfer function syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsfmj) or you'll have [numerical-precission issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665440/2586922)

Comment: Sorry, you want a FIR filter. Butterworth filters are IIR. I'll keep the comment in case it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

16 taps is not much to work with for an FIR filter, so I'm a dubious whether satisfying results are possible with any design. That said, I suggest trying Remez, aka Parks–McClellan optimal FIR filter design. See [Matlab's firpm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html) function. FIR filters designed by the Remez algorithm are "optimal" in the sense of minimizing the maximum pointwise error. Anthor plus about Remez is it allows setting different importance on each band, which could be useful to balance the tradeoff between passband flatness vs. stopband attenuation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have played with the firpm function in Matlab. However, how do I go from playing with different weights to actually having a strategy on how to get the optimal results? What's more important to set? Are there any mathematical calculations that would help get the best ranges? I'm new to this and I want to see if there's more to this than intuition or blindly trying everything.

Comment: Start with a simple bandpass specification with equal weights, then tweak the weights and band edges to trade among passband flatness, stopband attenuation, and transition width. I'm sorry this answer is lame. There are standard designs that are optimal by some definition of "optimal" or another, but no preeminently optimal design that is best for all purposes. Filter design in practice is a balancing act—the usual story of engineering. Improving one thing generally requires giving up some on something else. How to balance is up to you.